# How do I allow a webpage to update while a javascript is running?

Tags: javascript, html

There has to be an easy way to do this, but I'm new to JS.

I have a javascript program that (1) takes user input, (2) updates the webpage based on that input, then (3) performs a lengthy calculation.  The trouble is that the webpage doesn't register the update till after the lengthy calculation.  Isn't there a way to pause execution so that the page can update before the long calculation?

I've tried setTimeout and window.setTimeout, but they made no difference.

The program is for playing a game: the user inputs a move, the script updates the position, then calculates its next move. postMessage prints text messages using div.innerHTML; buttonFn takes the input from the user, updates the position, prints a message, then starts the computer calculating.

```
function buttonFn(arg){
    var hst = histButt;
    hst.push(arg);
    var nwmv = hst.clone();

    postMessage("New move: " + nwmv.join());
    if(status == opposite(comp) && !pauseQ){
    var mvsposs = movesFromPos(posCur,status);
    if(mvsposs.has(nwmv)){
        updatePosCur(nwmv);
        //waitasec();
        if(comp == status && !pauseQ){
        compTurn();
        };
    }
    else{
        histButt = nwmv;
    };
    };
};
```

Comment: A code sample would help here...

Comment: all process are being processed on client side?

Comment: function postMessage(txt){
    messageHist.push(txt);
    messageHist = messageHist.slice(1);
    
    var mesdiv = document.getElementById("messageDiv");
    //messageHist.reverse();
    mesdiv.innerHTML = messageHist.join("<br />");
    //messageHist.reverse();
};

Comment: function buttonFn(arg){
    var hst = histButt;
    hst.push(arg);
    var nwmv = hst.clone();
    
    postMessage("New move: " + nwmv.join());
    if(status == opposite(comp) && !pauseQ){
 var mvsposs = movesFromPos(posCur,status);
 if(mvsposs.has(nwmv)){
     updatePosCur(nwmv);
     //waitasec();
     if(comp == status && !pauseQ){
  compTurn();
     };
 }
 else{
     histButt = nwmv;
 };
    };
};

Comment: Yes, everything is done client side.  The program is for playing a game: the user inputs a move, the script updates the position, then calculates its next move.  postMessage prints text messages using div.innerHTML; buttonFn takes the input from the user, updates the position, prints a message, then starts the computer calculating.

Comment: use a spinner while processing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352/how-to-show-a-spinner-while-loading-an-image-via-javascript

Comment: Put the code in the original question, not the comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes there is, call your function like this.  Using setTimeout will allow a page reflow prior to your JS executing.

```
function buttonFn(arg){
    var hst = histButt;
    hst.push(arg);
    var nwmv = hst.clone();

    postMessage("New move: " + nwmv.join());
    if(status == opposite(comp) && !pauseQ){
    var mvsposs = movesFromPos(posCur,status);
    if(mvsposs.has(nwmv)){
        updatePosCur(nwmv);
        //waitasec();

        if(comp == status && !pauseQ){
        setTimeout(function(){
          compTurn();
        },0);

        };
    }
    else{
        histButt = nwmv;
    };
    };
};
```

Remember, JS is very event driven friendly.  If you can move things off, and call them later do it.  Thats the only way we can support multi-threaded like behavior.

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Comment: What does the parameter of 0 ms mean?

Comment: It tells the JS engine to delay execution.  By putting your long running function in a function closure as so, JS will execute the remaining part of buttonFn then execute whatever is inside the setTimeout.  If there is a browser reflow (DOM changed), this will occur as well before compTurn runs

Comment: Thanks! That worked!   But why is it necessary to wrap compTurn() in a function construct?  And why 0ms rather than say, 100ms?

Comment: You can put whatever you want, but I don't think you want compTurn to run later.  You just want the application to be responsive.  setTimeout executes the function passed to it after a so many milliseconds, in this case 0ms.  If you just put setTimeout above your compTurn(), it will execute nothing after 0ms and continue running the rest of your code in procedural fashion.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think my mistake was just using setTimeout(compTurn(),100), I didn't realize the expression has to be wrapped.  Quoting it seems to work also.

Comment: @Andrew `setTimeout(compTurn())` first *executes* `compTurn()`, then passes the result of that function to `setTimeout()`. Use an anonymous function wrap like Drew demonstrates or just *pass* the function like `setTimeout(compTurn)` *without executing it* (no `()`). `setTimeout('compTurn()')` works too, but differently and not in all situations.

Comment: OK, I think I've got it.  Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Don't worry, it took me a while to figure out the screwy behavior of setTimeout.  It is a pretty crappy function to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to support modern browsers (or if you use a transpiler), you can now use ES6 features to make this much easier and more in the style the original questioner was trying to do. (I realize the question is 8 years old - no harm in a new, more current answer!)

For example you can do something like this:

```
// helper function to use a setTimeout as a promise.
function allowUpdate() {
  return new Promise((f) => {
    setTimeout(f, 0);
  });
}

// An infinitely looping operation that doesn't crash the browser.
async function neverStopUpdating(someElement) {
  let i = 0;
  while (true) {
    someElement.innerText = i;
    i++;
    await allowUpdate();
  }
}
```

If you're trying to do a hard computation you'll want to make sure not to do this await too frequently - in this example, in Chrome at time of writing, `i` only increments by about 150 per second because the context switch of a setTimeout is not fast (where you'd get hundreds of thousands in a second if you didn't yield for updates). You'd likely want to find a balance, either always perform some number of iterations before allowing an update, or maybe eg. call Date.now() in your loop and yield for an update whenever 100ms have passed since the last time you allowed an update.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the update, wait for a bit of time, than do the calculation.

OR

You can use [webworkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers) on browsers that support them.

Without having actual code, that is the best answer that I can give you.

Comment: Never heard of webworkers, I'll check that out, thanks.  How do I "wait a bit of time"?  I thought that's what setTimeout was supposed to do.

Comment: @Andrew, well if setTimeout is not working, sounds like you are not allowing for enough time for the redraw to happen.

Comment: I've tried giving it as much as 5 seconds, shouldn't that be enough?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single threaded.  If you do your calc server side you could get the results via ajax which is called asynchronously, not blocking your ui.

Comment: Because the computations can be lengthy I thought it more appropriate to have the client do them.