# Display spinner while waiting for an image to display from an action

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a page in my MVC 3 project that pulls a report from reporting services, the result of which is displayed in an :

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller",...etc
```

This image is rendered at the bottom of the page.  The Action returns a FileContentResult and can take a few seconds to display.

What I want to do is display a spinner whilst the image is being returned.  The problem I have (and I've searched a ton about this) is that it's not ajax, not using JQuery, it's just effectively a plain old URL that the browser uses to retrieve the image.

So the question is, how do I display a spinner whilst it's waiting?  Is this even possible?  Or will I have to use JQuery/Ajax to load the image somewhere else and then display it?

Comment: Have you tried using alt="spinner.gif"?

Comment: Nice idea JackalopeZero, but unfortunately it didn't work :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show a spinner while loading an image via JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352/how-to-show-a-spinner-while-loading-an-image-via-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

This is how I do it. I normally add this to my _layout page so that this script and div are loaded on every page of my project. This will cause the Spinner to show any time there is a ajaxSend and hide on ajaxStop or ajaxError.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            BindSpinner();
        });

        function BindSpinner() {
            $("#spinner").bind("ajaxSend", function () {
                $(this).show();
            }).bind("ajaxStop", function () {
                $(this).hide();
            }).bind("ajaxError", function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        };
    </script>



  <div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display: none;">
       <img id="img-spinner" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif")" alt="Loading..." />
  </div>
```

Now anytime ajax causes the UI to wait the spinner will be shown.

A guide to calling an action using ajax can be found [here.](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/11/ajax-calls-to-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-using-jquery/)

Comment: really great way to add the waiting scenario in ajax calls before this I uses callbacks for every ajax call, you really open my eyes also the way to write call backs is really  cumbersome.. this is great +1 for you and thanks a lot..................
:D

Comment: Thanks Totero - looks like a really neat way of doing it.  I guess that means there's no way of doing it without using Ajax though?  As I'm not using any form of ajax at the moment...

Comment: I don't think so because you are making a synchronous request it won't be able to display a spinner in the way I think you intend. Ajax is asynchronous so it can. Why not use an ajax request?

Comment: Your right - I think I need to just to an ajax request.  I was doing it that way for simplicity's sake - the img tag only needs it's src to be the action, nice and simple and it just works, but it does mean there's a delay before showing the image and that delay is a bit rubbish from the UI perspective!  Thanks for your responses :)

Comment: AWESOME ANSWER DUDE - DA BOMB

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I had a similar problem and I have written a jQuery plugin which handles displaying a spinner automatically http://denysonique.github.com/imgPreload/