# after changing src of img display processing.gif untill real img loads

Tags: jquery, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show a spinner while loading an image via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352/how-to-show-a-spinner-while-loading-an-image-via-javascript)

I have an img, next btn and previous btn

Next button loads next image as

```
crntSrc=$("img").attr('src');
nextSrc=(crntSrc+1);
$("img").attr('src',nextSrc);
```

but I want to show process.gif image until nextSrc completely loads.

Comment: Similar question : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635388/how-to-display-loading-image-while-actual-image-is-downloading

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/q/51352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
function preload(src, cb)
{
    var img = new Image();
    img.load = cb;
    img.src = src;
}

var newImage = "/foo/foo.jpg";

// Function is called after image is loaded into memory.
preload(newImage, function(){
    $("#afterloadimg").attr("src", this.src);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set the process.gif as background of your image in css:

```
​img{
 background:url('process.gif') no-repeat center;   
}
```

​