# Placeholder while an image is loading with Ember.js

Tags: javascript, image, ember.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show a spinner while loading an image via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352/how-to-show-a-spinner-while-loading-an-image-via-javascript)

I'm displaying a list of Articles, where each article has an image. It looks something like this

[image: mockup]

The issue is that the view renders before the images are downloaded and it displays an empty box before the image is loaded.

Is there a good way that I could display some kind of a placeholder while the image is being loaded, and then just swap it once the image loads?

Comment: What'd be the placeholder for you? Some text? Or another image?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Another image, for example some loader.