# Show text while loading images

Tags: jquery

I'm making a website with a full background slider, so the images are kinda large. I want a script that shows some text with an animation effect while the background images are loading. I already searched for this, but no success. Can someone help me further?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show a spinner while loading an image via JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352/how-to-show-a-spinner-while-loading-an-image-via-javascript)

Comment: Is loading .gif acceptable http://preloaders.net/?

Comment: Not really, I want a first screen with a text animation with some delays to show the logo + the name of the website + maybe a gif to see that the images are loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display text by default, remove it on `$(img).load()`. Animate the text however you want with `.animate()`. If you change picture, insert the `spanLoading` again and repeat these steps.

```
<div>
    <img src="book.png" alt="Book" id="book" />
    <span id="spanLoading">Loading...</span>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //animate loading text
        $("#spanLoading").animate({left: '+=50'},500); 

        //On img loaded, remove loading text
        $("#book").load(){
            $("#spanLoading").remove();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to load dynamically your background image with the function

```
 $(function()){
   $("#background").attr('src','your_image here');
 }
```

and set the animation image as default background in your hTML code

then you will have your effect.