# Using spinners while waiting the image to be loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to use spinner images while the image is loading, and then I saw this thread:

[How to show a spinner while loading an image via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352/how-to-show-a-spinner-while-loading-an-image-via-javascript)

I did quite some search but I still don't quite understand in the accepted answer why put `objImagePreloader.onload=function(){};` in another `onload`function or how exactly it works. Could someone explain to me? It might be obvious but I am rather new to web design and any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
YL

Comment: Oh, I see the how callback works, question modeified.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever You create/preloading an image the onload function stands for:
   image  has been loaded....now You can elaborate
So in your case setting 
    objImagePreloader.onload=function(){};
means do nothing on image just loaded because you will use your callback function to do the task.

Hope this answer be enough clear.

by gm

Comment: Yeah...I got what you mean, but why is it necessary since the callback will be called anyways? I don't understand why the `if({}` and `else{}` looks exactly the same....