# Don't display an image until it's loaded

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```js
// Code goes here

angular
  .module('imgapp', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl);
  
function mainCtrl() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.first = {
    title: 'Image 1',
    url: 'http://www.image-mapper.com/photos/original/missing.png'
  }
  
  vm.second = {
    title: 'Image 2',
    url: 'http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/conquer/assets/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg'
  }
  
  vm.primary = vm.first;
  
  vm.changeObject = function() {
    vm.primary = vm.second;
  }
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="imgapp">
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.9" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
    <button ng-click="vm.changeObject();">Change object</button>
    <h1>{{vm.primary.title}}</h1>
    <img ng-src="{{vm.primary.url}}">
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a block with a title and an image in it. Data in this block **can** be changed, therefore another image should be loaded.
If you have slow internet connection, you can see that the title was changed, where image **wasn't**, cause it hasn't loaded yet.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/wfzWKIeu1vllJKAzBJde?p=preview):  (press `change object` to load a new image and change the title)

**How can I hide an old image until a new image has been loaded?**

*Note: I don't use jQuery*

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352/how-to-show-a-spinner-while-loading-an-image-via-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/byJc95CyVaxNJYOxqblW?p=info)

I have just created a directive which will call a function upon image load.

```
.directive('imageonload', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          ngShow : '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function() {
                alert('image is loaded');
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.ngShow = true;  
                });

            });
            element.bind('error', function(){
                alert('image could not be loaded');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And modified html like,

```
<img ng-show="vm.isImageVisible" ng-src="{{vm.primary.url}}" imageonload >
```

Comment: is there anyway we can apply css while show and hide of image?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for ng-cloak directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

So your example can look like this:

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
  <button ng-click="vm.changeObject();">Change object</button>
  <div ng-cloak>
    <h1>{{vm.primary.title}}</h1>
    <img ng-src="{{vm.primary.url}}">
  </div>
</body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/rf8hM9JvR7EnjS1eWOgp?p=preview

Comment: It doesn't show the image until it's loaded, however it doesn't hide the old one

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
var image = imageDomReferenceHere;
var downloadingImage = new Image();
downloadingImage.onload = function(){
   image.src = this.src;   
};
downloadingImage.src = "image path here";
```

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/learn-asynchronous-image-loading-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two steps. First add **ng-show** to hide or show element when it is loading. Second use **onLoad** event to know when it is done loading. I picked directive from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884399/image-loaded-event-in-for-ng-src-in-angularjs)

**html**

```
vm.notLoading = true;
vm.imageLoaded = imageLoaded;
```

**directive**

```
function imageonload() {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('load', function() {
            //call the function that was passed
            scope.$apply(attrs.imageonload);
        });
    }
}
```

**controller**

```
...

vm.notLoading = true;
vm.imageLoaded = imageLoaded;

...

vm.changeObject = function() {
    vm.notLoading = false;
    vm.primary = vm.second;
}

function imageLoaded() {
    vm.notLoading = true;
}
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fmst3xQfXaEHbMkkqy7N?p=preview)